# Finding minimum $\sqrt{x^2-3x+3}+\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q. Finding minimum $f(x)$
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-3x+3}+\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}$$

Comment: what is your domain? and also, what have you tried? have you tried differentiation?

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Since
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-3x+3}+\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} = \sqrt{\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2 + \dfrac34} + \sqrt{\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2 - \dfrac14},$$
we have $\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2 + \dfrac34 \ge \dfrac14+\dfrac34 = 1$.